# Running MATLAB function without defining all parameters

Tags: matlab

I have a Matlab function

```
PlotSubbands(imfx(:,1),wx,3,3,j,j,1);ylabel('Subband');
```

from TQWT toolbox. [eeweb.poly.edu/iselesni/TQWT](http://eeweb.poly.edu/iselesni/TQWT). When I execute, the function plots 'j' number of plots. (I have not included full code). The function plots the input signal, which is in this case imfx(:,1) for every subplot. And this what I don't want. I tried removing it from the parameters but I got error, 'not enough input arguments'. This is because in the function the first input signal parameters is defined and used. I cannot remove it from there. Appreciate your inputs on the same. Thank you.

Comment: You cant run a function without defining all parameters, unless the function allows not to have all inputs, and in that case, well, you are defining all its parameters

Comment: Exactly, @Ander Biguri. A Matlab function can not run without defining all parameters. Now this function is plotting the input signal for all subplots because it is defined. Should I find the way to stop this repeated plotting of input in the function itself?

Comment: I found the solution by modifying the function. Thank you @Ander Biguri for the inputs.

Comment: Hi @Dattaprasad, please answer your question below and share the code.

Answer (score 0):

The function PlotSubbands include following lines

```
if isreal(x)
plot((0:N-1)/fs,x/(2*max(abs(x))),'b')
else
plot((0:N-1)/fs, real(x)/(2*max(abs(x))), 'black')
```

The repeated plotting of input signal is done from these two line. Commenting these lines can solve the problem (If array x does not include imaginary part, then better to comment these lines). However, the to determine the real array, isreal(x) is needed further in the function. So, I defined the value of x here and it solved the repeated plotting issue.